# Perl Printing arbitrary number of hash values of 2 arrays of hashes

Tags: arrays, perl, multidimensional-array, hash

I am trying to find a way to print the subhash values of a pair of arrays of hashes in the same loop.

This is how my hash looks like:

```
$VAR1 = {
    'countrya' => [
                   [ { 'area' => 'statea', 'population' => '10' }, 
                     { 'area' => 'stateb', 'population' => '20' } ], # previous
                   [ { 'area' => 'statea', 'population' => '30' }, 
                     { 'area' => 'stateb', 'population' => '40' } ] # current      
               ],
    'countryb' => [
                   [ { 'area' => 'statec', 'population' => '50' }, 
                     { 'area' => 'stated', 'population' => '60' } ], # previous
                   [ { 'area' => 'statec', 'population' => '70' }, 
                     { 'area' => 'stated', 'population' => '80' } ] # current 
               ]
}
```

And this is the output of what I am hoping to achieve:

```
countrya
*****
statea -> 10
statea -> 30

stateb -> 20
stateb -> 40

countryb
*****
statec -> 50
statec -> 70

stated -> 60
stated -> 80
```

The first array of subhashes in `countrya` and `countryb` represents previous values, while the second array represent current values. And therefore the values have to be printed after the other.

So far I have managed to get the output that I want through this loop:

```
foreach my $h (keys %countries) {
    print "$h\n";
    foreach my $i ($countries{$h}) {
        print "$$i[0][0]{'area'} -> ";
        print "$$i[0][0]{'population'}\n";
        print "$$i[1][0]{'area'} -> ";
        print "$$i[1][0]{'population'}\n";
        print "$$i[0][1]{'area'} -> ";
        print "$$i[0][1]{'population'}\n";
        print "$$i[1][1]{'area'} -> ";
        print "$$i[1][1]{'population'}\n";
    } 
}
```

However, the above code only works with the assumption that there are only two subhashes in each array. How should I modify the code to support any number of subhashes?

Comment: Its actually not that clear what you are looking for...do you want to iterate over pairs subhashes in your array and compare values?

Comment: Yes, I want to iterate over 2 pairs of arrays which contains n number of subhashes.